# Debugger do Eclipse não avança em aplicação Android

Tags: android, eclipse, debug

Estou tendo um problema ao tentar debugar uma aplicação Android no Eclipse. Quando aperto as teclas F5, F6 ou F8 , simplesmente a linha do break point não passa para próxima instrução (linha), fica parada. Já havia usado o Debug do Eclipse e nunca tinha tido problemas.

Vejam a imagem da tela do meu Eclipse e o código que estou tentando debugar.
Já tentei resumir, mas mesmo assim o break point não avança para próxima linha.

[image: Tela do Eclipse]

```
    void init(){
    txtFrequencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Frequencia);
    txtQuantidade = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Quantidade);
    txtIntervalo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Intervalo);
    txtNomeMedicamento = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_NomeMedicamento);
    tmpInicioTratamento = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker_InicioTratamento);
    spnTipoDosagem = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_TipoDosagem);
    btnSalvar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_salvar_agenda);

    toast = Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Você Apertou o Botão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    btnSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            add();

        }
    });
}
```

Obs: Já testei em duas versões do Eclipse e estou usando o Windows 8 64 bits

Comment: Dê uma olhada na abinha Debug, lá tem as Threads que estão correndo. Veja se tem alguma com um pause. Se tiver esse pode ser o problema.

Comment: Como corrijo isso? Realmente a thread está suspended

Comment: Clica com um botão direito e selecione resume.

Comment: Tentei resumir, mas quando aperto F5, F6 etc o break point não muda de linha.

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551818/how-to-debug-android-application-line-by-line-using-eclipse

Comment: @user5172 Lembre que, caso você queira dizer mais coisas sobre o seu problema (como o exemplo de código que você postou) **editar** sua pergunta é sempre melhor que adicionar uma resposta. É a melhor maneira de garantir que todo mundo vai ler. Bem vindo ao SOPT :)

Comment: Eu já tentei de tudo. O que estou acreditando agora que isso pode ser um bug do ADT ou tem alguma coisa a ver com a versão da aplicação Android que estou criando. Vou criar uma nova aplicação com uma versão mais inferior para testar. Deixo todos informado sobre o resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver você deve de estar com o problema de mapeamento de teclas de atalho do eclipse.
Minha sugestão é que você reset para as configurações originais. em:

Window > Preference > General > Keys

Selecione o Scheme Default e depois click no botão "Restore Defaults".

Caso o problema ainda ocorra verifique se você consegue seguir os próximos passos pelo atalho no menu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mesmo clicando nos botões da barra de ferramentas o negócio não funciona.

Comment: Tenta da um reset na perspective de Debug no Eclipse. Outra duvida isso só acontece em um projeto android? Se voce criar um projeto java normal ele funciona o Debug?

Comment: Outra dica é ativar o DebugMode no manisfest do projeto.

Comment: Testei com um projeto Java comum e funciona e no manifest já estava ativo a opção debug

Answer (score 0):

Nas vezes que tive este problema, pode ser duas coisas:

1. A janela do Eclipse está fora de foco. Clicando dentro dela os comandos voltam a funcionar;
2. A Thread selecionada na perspectiva de Debug não é a mesma Thread que está suspensa. Neste caso, eu tinha que achar na lista a Thread que aparece com um ícone amarelo de pausa, clicar nela pra daí ter os comandos funcionando de volta.

Comment: E como corrijo essa questão da Thread. A thread aparece como suspended.

Comment: Só clicar em cima dela e comandar o F6 ou por atalho ou pelo botão verde de play.